# Insufficient numerical precision of LAPACK procedures (Fortran 90)?

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, fortran90, lapack, polynomials

I have written a simple Fortran code which carries out polynomial interpolation of `n+1` points of `R^2`. It solves a system of linear equations (I am creating Vandermonde matrix) with two `LAPACK` procedures (everything is double precision in my code):
At first, it factorises the matrix: [http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/nacphy/lapack/routines/dgetrf.html](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/%7Elandaur/nacphy/lapack/routines/dgetrf.html)
Later, it solves the system: [http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~landaur/nacphy/lapack/routines/dgetrs.html](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/%7Elandaur/nacphy/lapack/routines/dgetrs.html)

the program works fine for a few tested cases of data produced from polynomials of degrees: 0,1,2,3,4. However, when I provide 11 points from a polynomial `P(x) = x^10` it infers completely wrong coefficients.

Input (`x..., y...`):

```
1.0
1.001
1.002
1.003
1.004
1.005
1.006
1.007
1.008
1.009
1.01
1.0
1.01004512021
1.02018096336
1.03040825707
1.04072773401
1.05114013204
1.06164619412
1.07224666847
1.08294230847
1.0937338728
1.10462212541
```

Output (`a_n,...,a_0`):

```
-4.6992230177E+004
2.2042918738E+005
-3.2949938635E+005
5.0740528522E+004
2.4764893257E+005
-3.1846974845E+004
-1.7195378863E+005
-1.4751075818E+005
4.1766709741E+005
-2.6476448046E+005
5.6082872757E+004
```

Am I hitting numerical stability problems? Or did I do something wrong?

---

Edit: I attach the code for the interpolation procedure (watch out, we actually have `n` points not `n+1`).

```
module InterpolatorModule
contains
subroutine interpolate(n, x, y, a)
  implicit none
  integer :: n, i, j, info
  integer, dimension (:), allocatable :: ipiv
  real(8), dimension (:), pointer :: x, y, a
  real(8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: Mat_X, Mat_B

  ! create the Vandermonde matrix:
  allocate ( Mat_X(n,n) )
  do i = 1,n
    do j = 1,n
      Mat_X(i,j) = x(i) ** ( n - j )
    end do
  end do

  ! reshape ipnut data into a matrix form:
  allocate ( Mat_B(n,1) )
  do i = 1,n
    Mat_B(i,1) = y(i)
  end do

  ! prepare an array for the pivot indices from DGETRF:
  allocate(ipiv(n))

  call DGETRF(n, n, Mat_X, n, ipiv, info)
  call DGETRS("N", n, 1, Mat_X, n, ipiv, Mat_B, n, info)

  ! save the results into the argument array
  do i = 1,n
    a(i) = Mat_B(i,1)
  end do

  deallocate(ipiv)
  deallocate ( Mat_X )
  deallocate ( Mat_B )

end subroutine interpolate
end module InterpolatorModule
```

---

Edit: the `main` program:

```
program MyInterpolation
use InterpolatorModule
implicit none

  integer :: line, n
  real(8), dimension (:), pointer :: p_x, p_y, p_a
  real(8), dimension(:), target, allocatable :: in1_x, in1_y, in1_a 
  character(len=23) :: str

  open (1, file="test/in.txt", status="old", action="read", form="formatted")

    n = 11 ! this value is not known at compulation time, simplification for SO

    ! allocate memory for the input data
    allocate ( in1_x(n) )
    allocate ( in1_y(n) )
    allocate ( in1_a(n) )

    ! read the x_i coordinates:
    do line = 1,n
      read(1,*) in1_x(line)
    end do
    ! read the y_i coordinates:
    do line = 1,n
      read(1,*) in1_y(line)
    end do
  close(1)
  ! assign pointers to the arrays:
  p_x => in1_x
  p_y => in1_y
  p_a => in1_a
  ! call the interpolating procedure:
  call interpolate(n, p_x, p_y, p_a)

  ! print out calculated coefficients:
  do line = 1,n
    write(str,'(ES23.10 E3)') in1_a(line)
    write(*,'(a)') adjustl(trim(str))
  end do

  ! free the allocated memory
  deallocate (in1_x)
  deallocate (in1_y)
  deallocate (in1_a)

  ! ===========================================================================

end program MyInterpolation
```

Comment: Vandermonde matrices are typically very badly ill-conditioned though I am a little surprised that such a small problem goes this badly wrong - can you show us your code, please? There are also special methods to invert Vandermonde matrices.

Comment: @IanBush : done!

Comment: A complete program showing the issue would make our life a lot easier ...

Comment: Need the code that calls your subroutine.  My first question would then likely be answered.  Why do x, y, and a have the pointer attribute?  BTW, you nested do-loops for filling `Mat_X` are backwards.

Comment: Done! I pass pointes to arrays into the subroutine; just for optimisation, thanks for noting the matrices are backwards!

Comment: A Fortran `pointer` is not the same thing as a C pointer.  Did you benchmark whether the use of `pointer` is faster than simply using `allocatable`?  Experience tells me one should avoid pointer if possible.

Comment: Also listen to @evets - the basic rule in Fortran is don't use pointers

Comment: The point of the whole program is so we can compile and test what you are doing. WE can't do that currently as you haven't supplied InterperlatorModule (I can guess what it is but would prefer not to) or the input file (similarly). A program without any input file and just "burnt in" values would be best

Comment: InterpolatorModule is a separate file which contains the procedure I posted. I modified the code so that is complete now.  
The input file I did provide - it is a text file `Input` which in the original post. It is better not to burn it in because maybe I am reading it wrong and that is the source of an error?

Comment: Sorry missed that. Busy now - will try to look later

Comment: @maciek Now that the posted code is complete, I compiled it with Intel Fortran 2013 and MKL (for LAPACK functions), but get completely different output: `-1.6446899734E+004
8.6913137627E+004
-1.6131059503E+005
8.3933953569E+004
9.6954750417E+004
-1.1750683590E+005
-9.7265524551E+003
4.3628899288E+004
1.3585888937E+004
-2.8138744982E+004
8.1139982612E+003`. I am looking through the code now.

Comment: @maciek The construction of the Vandermonde matrix looks strange to me. I would have expected it to be organized as shown in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), but looking at the code and printing out the matrix shows that is not the case. Am I missing something?

Comment: @njuffa as it was pointed out in the previous comment, the columns are in reverse order (first column should be the last column etc.) I have corrected for that with changing the power from `(n - j)` to `(j - 1)`. The results are similar, the problem persists...

Comment: @maciek Looks like a numerical issue. Already at degree 5 polynomial relevant elements in the matrix produced by `GETRF` are down to magnitude 1e-14 (i.e. getting close to double-precision epsilon), and the accuracy of the solution suffers significantly. I used Wolfram Alpha as a reference. The Vandermonde matrix approach is not suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is widely recognized – and has been pointed out in comments – that the Vandermonde matrix is frequently ill-conditioned. For example a standard textbook on numerical analysis, D. Kincaid and W. Cheney, "Numerical Analysis, 2nd ed.", Brooks/Cole Publishing 1996, states on page 336:

> The coefficient matrix in Equation (12) is called the **Vandermonde matrix**. It is non-singular because the system has a unique solution for any choice of *y<sub>0</sub>*, *y<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *y<sub>n</sub>* [...]. The determinant of the Vandermonde matrix is therefore nonzero for distinct nodes *x<sub>0</sub>*, *x<sub>1</sub>*, ..., *x<sub>n</sub>*. [...] However, the Vandermonde matrix is often *ill conditioned*, and the coefficients *a<sub>i</sub>* may therefore be inaccurately determined by solving System (12). (See Gautschi [1984]). [...] Therefore, this approach is *not* recommended.

Inspection of the matrix returned by `GETRF` already informs us that we are in trouble for polynomials of fairly low degrees. At degree 4 the magnitude of the smallest relevant element after LU decomposition is on the order of 10<sup>-12</sup>, and at degree 5 the smallest such element is 10<sup>-14</sup>. Based on the fact that all elements of the original matrix were near unity, and knowing the basic steps of the LU decomposition process, it is clear that the tiny elements in the `GETRF` result come about by subtractive cancellation.

The magnitude of the elements getting close to the double precision epsilon (≈ 10<sup>-16</sup>) tells us that most of the accuracy has been lost. For polynomials of degrees 6 and higher the code is basically operating on pure noise.

We can further confirm this by comparing the computed coefficients of the interpolation polynomial with a more robust reference. For simplicity I used Wolfram Alpha for this comparison. For a degree 4 polynomial, the Fortran code computes the coefficients accurate to about three decimal digits, and for a polynomial of degree 5, this shrinks to a single correct decimal digit.

In terms of a *simple* and more robust algorithm to generate the coefficients of the interpolation polynomial, I found the following:

J. N. Lyness and C.B. Moler, "Van Der Monde Systems and Numerical Differentiation." *Numerische Mathematik* 8, 458-464 (1966)

I translated the Algol code in the paper to ISO-C99 and it seems to deliver reasonable results up to degree 8 by comparison with Wolfram Alpha. Wolfram Alpha gives up for degrees greater than 8, and I do not have another reference handy. Even with this more robust algorithm there seems to be significant loss of precision for higher degrees, with only 6 decimal digits matching between Wolfram Alpha and the Luness/Moler algorithm.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* J. N. Lyness and C.B. Moler, "Van Der Monde Systems and Numerical 
   Differentiation." Numerische Mathematik 8, 458-464 (1966)
*/
void update (int k, int p, double *x, double fxk, double *C)
{
    int d, s, m, n;
    double xk, xkd;
    xk = x[k];
    m = k*(k+3)/2;
    C[m] = fxk;
    for (d = 1; d <= k; d++) {
        xkd = xk - x[k-d];
        for (s = 0; s <= ((d > p) ? p : d); s++) {
            m = m - 1;
            n = m + d;
            if (s == 0) {
                C[m] = C[n] + xk * (C[n-k-1] - C[n]) / xkd;
            } else if (s == d) {
                C[m] = (C[n+1] - C[n-k]) / xkd;
            } else {
                C[m] = C[n] + (xk * (C[n-k-1] - C[n]) + (C[n+1] - C[n-k]))/ xkd;
            }
            if (d > p) {
                m = m - d + p;
            }
        }
    }        
}

/* Solve (k+1) x (k+1) system Vc = f, where V[i,j] = x[i]**j  */
void vandal (int k, double *x, double *f, double *c)
{
    double C [k*(k+3)/2+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        update (i, k, x, f[i], C);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        c[i] = C[k-i];
    }
}

#define k 10
int main (void)
{
    double x[k+1] = {1.000, 1.001, 1.002, 1.003, 1.004, 1.005, 
                     1.006, 1.007, 1.008, 1.009, 1.010};
    double f[k+1] = {1.00000000000, 1.01004512021, 1.02018096336, 
                     1.03040825707, 1.04072773401, 1.05114013204, 
                     1.06164619412, 1.07224666847, 1.08294230847, 
                     1.09373387280, 1.10462212541};
    double c[k+1] = {0};
    
    vandal (k, x, f, c);

    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        printf ("c[%2d] = % 23.16e\n", i, c[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Another place you might look is https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/f_src.html where there are a number of vandermonde matrix related routines in Fortran - caveat, I haven't tested or looked at any of them